# Some Xcode build settings are missing

Tags: xcode5

Top in the screenshot is an Xcode project from someone else, bottom is a project created by me, both are C/C++ library projects.

My project settings is missing the whole Apple LLVM 5.1 - Language section amongst others.
Am I missing an option in Xcode to make these visible or could it be because the 3rd party project was created with Xcode 3, my project with Xcode 5 and these settings aren't available anymore?

[image: XCode build settings]

Answer (score 0):

The missing settings magically appeared after adding header/source files and invoking the first build process.